# Reflexive calls of objects in the same hierarchy

Tags: abstraction, recursion, hierarchy, circular-dependency

I am not sure how to phrase this. I believe this should have been asked somewhere, but I am unable to find it because I don't know the keywords.

Basically, I have some types like this:

```
interface Foo
    class Bar0 extends Foo
    class Bar1 extends Foo
    class Bar2 extends Foo
```

And `Foo` is an interface like this:

```
interface Foo{
    Result compare(Foo other);
}
```

The `Foo.compare(Foo)` method is reflexive, i.e. `assert a.compare(b).equals(b.compare(a))`. Therefore, the implementation of `Bar0.compare(other)` where `other` is an instance of `Bar1`, should have the same (except swapping of `this` and `other`) implementation as `Bar1.compare(other)` where `other` is an instance of `Bar0`.

Therefore, I obviously shouldn't implement both of them. For example, if I implemented for `Bar0.compare(Bar1)`, `Bar1.compare(Bar0)` should redirect to a reflexive call (`return other.compare(this);`). However, it is very inconvenient because I have to ensure that only one is implemented, and avoid accidental mutual recursion. Apparently, in my real implementation, the subclasses aren't named `Bar0`, `Bar1` and `Bar2`.

Is there any convenient, reliable and effective method to implement this to ensure that mutual recursion or repeated implementation wouldn't happen?

Also, is there a term for this situation? (I want to do some research myself, but I don't even know the keywords)

Comment: Surely the method belongs to the class not the instance

Comment: @Ewan what do you mean?

Comment: "I have a hierarchy of objects". We typically speak of classes in hierarchy, rather than objects in hierarchy (unless the objects are arranged in an org chart or something).  You might be conflating terminology of classes and objects (instances), which makes for confusion.

Comment: yes i assumed you meant you had Foo.Bar1 etc rather than Bar1 : Foo

Comment: What language are you talking about? It might change the answer a bit.

Comment: Should apply to most object-oriented languages, but Java in specific. However, I (and future readers) may also be interested if some language features systems that can solve this problem more conveniently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you should implement

```
IComparer 
{
    Result Compare(Foo,Foo)
    bool CanCompare(type1,type2)
}
```

as a Type specific version

```
ComparerBar1Bar2 : IComparer
{
    Compare(Foo first ,Foo other)
    {
        return (Bar1)first == (Bar2)other;
    }

    bool CanCompare(type1,type2)
    {
        return type1 = Bar1 and type2 = Bar2;        
    }
}
```

and inject a set of them into the instances of your classes

```
Foo
{
    Compare(Foo other)
    {
         iComparer = mycomparers.getComparer(this.Type,other.type)
         iComparer(this, other)

         //if we couldnt find one...
         iComparer = mycomparers.getComparer(other.type, this.type)
         iComparer(other, this)
    }
}
```

If the comparison never changes you can have this list as a static instead of injecting, but remember to ensure you can call the correctly overridden comparers in sub classes

Comment: I feel that there is something wrong, but I don'tn know how to describe that feeling. It feels strange if you (1) create a class that joins two classes -- if I have `n` subclasses, won't there be `0.5n(n-1)` comparator classes? The reason I'm using inheritance here is that there might be a lot of subclasses. (2) implement things directly related to that class itself in another class?

Comment: well if you sub class comparison is the same as the parent class you don't need to implement a new comparer. But if all your subclasses can be compared as Foo... you can just implement the comparison once in Foo, so you dont have a problem

Comment: re the tight coupling in the comparer, its better than tight coupling the Bar classes by implementing the type safe comparison in them directly

Comment: updated to reflect your inheritance

Comment: I guess it is also possible that all comparator methods are implemented in a single utility class.

Comment: I would advise against big helper classes